# Alternatives to jQuery UI Resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of any alternative jQuery plugins to the resizable function in jQuery UI? My main focus is on constraining the bounding box (parent), and the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the CSS "resize" attribute. See this page: http://www.css3.info/preview/resize/

Answer (score -4):

I don't know why you need an alternative if you can do that with jQuery UI resizable.

Here are some demos:

- [preserve aspect ratio](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#aspect-ratio)
- [contrain resize area](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#constrain-area)
- [max/min size](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#max-min)

All you need to do is just set your image CSS styles so that it resizes with the resizable box.

Comment: I am looking for an alternative, because jquery UI is bloated.

Comment: Not at all, you don't have to load the whole UI. You just load the parts you want to use.

Comment: I can't speak for OP, but I'll tell you why I'm looking for one.  Resizable is buggy, buggy, buggy.  It doesn't work properly in popups, it doesn't work -at all- for resizing tables.

Comment: Yes, it's buggy and horrible and jquery UI should be avoided at all costs because it's a giant bag of suck. And that's really a non-answer.